# Background Task 9 ("SKReceiptRefreshRequest"), was created over 30 seconds ago?

Tags: swift, xcode, in-app-purchase

i am using [SwiftyStoreKit](https://github.com/bizz84/SwiftyStoreKit) SDK for in app purchase into my application

for some reason , the restore is not working and i am getting this message in xCode console

Log :

```
[BackgroundTask] Background Task 1 ("SKReceiptRefreshRequest"), was created over 30 seconds
     ago. In applications running in the background, this creates a risk of termination. Remember to
     call UIApplication.endBackgroundTask(_:) for your task in a timely manner to avoid this.
```

My restore purchase code :

```
SwiftyStoreKit.restorePurchases(atomically: true) { results in
    if results.restoreFailedPurchases.count > 0 {
        print("Restore Failed: \(results.restoreFailedPurchases)")
    }
    else if results.restoredPurchases.count > 0 {


SwiftyStoreKit.fetchReceipt(forceRefresh: true) { result in
    switch result {
    case .success(let receiptData):
        let encryptedReceipt = receiptData.base64EncodedString(options: [])
        print("Fetch receipt success:\n\(encryptedReceipt)")
    case .error(let error):
        print("Fetch receipt failed: \(error)")
    }
}

        print("Restore Success: \(results.restoredPurchases)")
    }
    else {
        print("Nothing to Restore")
    }
}
```

and its keep loading forever without any progress , any idea why ?

Comment: did you got answer,I am not using SwiftyStorekit but, i am also facing same issue ?

Comment: @guru i've wrote my own swift IAP class and its working very fine

Comment: Just add request.cancel() in requestDidFinish(_ request: SKRequest) it is becoause it is not deallocated.

Answer (score 6):

(in Objective C) I can't speak to why SwiftyStoreKit is not working but the error message is the same as a bug  for an SKReceiptRefreshRequest in the method `[request start];`.  When the request is returned in `requestDidFinish:` the request is not properly dealloc'd and needs a `[request cancel];`